# What is the difference between using brackets "[]" and parentheses "()" for "fields" in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have seen fields in the django-rest-framework initialized/declared with parentheses `()` and brackets `[]` and I am wondering if there is a difference.

I have only been using () but I see [] in the documentation everywhere.

Say we have a model Dog.

```py
class Dog(models.Model):
    favorite_food = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now would it be correct to say that these two serializers below for this Dog model are the same? Even though the `field` is declared with different ASCII characters.

```py
class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Dog
         fields = ('id', 'favorite_food')
```

```py
class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Dog
         fields = ['id', 'favorite_food']
```

Comment: Checking. Might delete this.

Comment: both are valid , and you should know the difference between set and list

Comment: Agreed. Django is how I am learning python and I ran across it. Glad I know it now.